# ConTeXt: Disable automatic conversion of arrows

Tags: math-mode, context

ConTeXt has the default setting to convert `->` to a right arrow, `<-` to a left arrow, and some more. I guess that can be neat in some cases, but if you want to compare two negative numbers, it will give an unwanted result:

```
\startTEXpage[offset=2bp]
If I write \type{$-2<-1$} I get $-2<-1$.
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: image showing the problem]

> **Question** How do I switch this feature off *globably* in my document?

(I have some vague memory of seing a discussion about this feature in the ConTeXt list, but I cannot find it, sorry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ulrike's solution is (almost) correct, but I would not advise to set `collapsing=none` (`0` doesn't exist and is thus interpreted as `none`).  That's because `collapsing` actually has three stages

- `1` specials
- `2` specials + mathlist
- `3` mathlist + sepcials

The replacement you observe is in the so called *mathlist* set.  The *specials* set on the other hand contains replacements which are suggested by the font (usually ligatures), such as collapsing of primes `′′′` to `‴`.

The difference between options `2` and `3` is only which of the two takes precedence, so in your case you want to switch to option `1`.

Compare those two:

```
\setupmathematics[collapsing=none]
\startTEXpage
$-2<-1$ $x'''$
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

```
\setupmathematics[collapsing=1]
\startTEXpage
$-2<-1$ $x'''$
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

---

You could also poke around in the Lua code and remove only this one specific collapsing.  This might be useful if you want to keep other replacements from the *mathlist* set, such as `:=` (`0x003A` COLON + `‎0x003D` EQUALS SIGN) to `≔` (`0x2254` COLON EQUALS).  For an overview consult section 1.1 of the [Math manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/math-mkiv.pdf).

```
\startluacode
characters.mathlists[0x3C][0x2212] = nil
\stopluacode
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\setupmathematics
  [collapsing=none]
\startTEXpage[offset=2bp]
If I write \type{$-2<-1$} I get $-2<-1$.
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, so `collapsing` it was. Many thanks!

Comment: It is `collapsing=none`.  The option `0` [doesn't exist](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/25fcad7435f56cdce2658336909f4da6a65589c0/tex/context/base/mkiv/math-ini.mkiv#L1440-L1444) and is conveniently interpreted as `none`.